# Distribution of the sum of absolutes values of T-distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convolution, independence, characteristic-functions

Where $X$ is a r.v. following a symmetric $T$ distribution with $0 $mean and tail parameter $\alpha$.

I am looking for the distribution of the $n$-summed independent variables $ \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n}|x_i|$.

$Y=|X|$ has for PDF $\frac{2 \left(\frac{\alpha }{\alpha +y^2}\right)^{\frac{\alpha +1}{2}}}{\sqrt{\alpha } B\left(\frac{\alpha }{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)}$, $y \geq 0 $. I managed to get the characteristic function $C(t)$ but could not invert the convolution, that is, $C(t)^n$.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: [Bounty: Intuition for Conditional Expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048219) (1. by linking bounty question here, this question gets attention because the bounty question is linked to this question. 2. by linking bounty question here, nero gets to see bounty question and so might answer bounty question)

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem using the bounty question's discussion thread? Thanks!